# php xml remove elements not containing a specific word from large file

Tags: php, xml

I am reading an xml file which looks like this but with a lot more products:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<products>
    <product>
        <company>company.com</company>
        <category>Category A</category>
        <brand>Alle!rgica</brand>
        <product_name>Name A</product_name>
        <productid>6230</productid>
        <description>A nice description</description>
        <price>125.50</price>
    </product>
    <product>
        <company>Team.com</company>
        <category>Category B // something</category>
        <brand>New Nordic > Healthcare</brand>
        <product_name>Name B</product_name>
        <productid>9489</productid>
        <description>Active Legs? Buy it now for free</description>
        <price>188.00</price>
    </product>
</products>
```

I want to read it and then save it with only products containing the word "free" somewhere in the "product tag" and without the "products" tag and the xml header.

I know how to read the file and save it, but I can't figure out the best approach to remove everything but the products that contain "free".

I tried wth Regex but it didn't seem the best solution (mainly because the matching doesn't properly work):

```
preg_match_all('/<product>(.*?)(free|free-stuff)(.*?)<\/product>/is', $data, $result);
```

So in the case of the above the file should only contain:

```
<product>
        <company>Team.com</company>
        <category>Category B // something</category>
        <brand>New Nordic > Healthcare æøå</brand>
        <product_name>Name B</product_name>
        <productid>9489</productid>
        <description>Active Legs? Buy it now for free</description>
        <price>188.00</price>
</product>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `xpath()`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($x); // assume XML in $x
$result = $xml->xpath("//product[not(contains(., 'free'))]");
```

`$result` contains an array of `<product>`-nodes as `SimpleXML`-elements that do not contain "free".

Output:

```
foreach ($result as $r)
    echo $r->asXML();
```

See it working: https://eval.in/338884

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file($filename);

foreach($xml->product as $product) {
    foreach($product->children() as $child)
// lookup the pattern in all nodes inside product
            if ($found = (false !== strpos((string)$child, 'free')))
// Found - we can don't continue searching 
                break; 
// save product found
        if ($found) $products[] =  $product;
    }
    print_r( $products);
```